# Why am I getting this error in Heroku: function requires at least protocol version 3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm playing around with the excellent [Rails 4 tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters) from Michael Hartl. I was lucky to have chosen Heroku as my production environment for this and to have found the tutorial afterwards.

That said, I'm now having some trouble with Heroku. I'm getting this error:

```
PG::UnableToSend: function requires at least protocol version 3.0
```

in the logs (`heroku logs`).

I'm not sure what is causing this exactly. My DB is tiny and even tinier in production (around 10 rows or something).

Has anyone had experience with this? I'd appreciate any assistance.

Comment: I experienced this last week on heroku.  I'm really not sure what caused it, because like you I had just gotten started with a project so it was an issue of an extraordinarily large db.  I dropped the database and reloaded, it was fine.  `heroku pg:reset DATABASE` then `heroku run rake db:migrate` and if you're seeding `heroku run rake db:seed`

Comment: after some time of inactivity (most of the day) my app started working again after I filed a ticket. It didn't sound like the tech didn't anything to fix it. Presumably resources just freed up or something.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this error happens on low memory conditions according to this [post](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAOtHd0C=sRitHx2GSPgoK2t1A70QJk4HB59QvB_pmMR7zaecgw@mail.gmail.com).

Comment: I confirm this is due to low memory issue